# Regarding Qml bindings

Tags: qt, qml

Why the below code is not working when clicked on cancel button ie., parameterValueText.text is not setting to value 0.

I am assuming both val and parameterValueText.text are binded eachother. If I am wrong, please correct me

Please find below steps

Step 1: Edit a value in Text Input, for ex: 1

Step 2: on Keyboard accepted, parameterValueText.onAccepted is called

Step 3: Click on Save, saveBtn.onClicked is called

Step 4: Click on Cancel, cancelBtn.onClicked is called but the parameterValueText.text is not changed to value 0.

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12
import QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard 2.1

ApplicationWindow {
id: window
width: 480
height: 272
visible: true
title: qsTr("Keyboard")

property int val: 0

Column {
    Item {
        id: itemId
        height: 20
        width: window.width

        Rectangle{
            width: 100
            height: itemId.height
            border.color:"black"

            TextInput {
                id: parameterValueText
                text: val     //Assuming text and val are  binded ??
                inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhDigitsOnly
                anchors.fill: parent
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                onAccepted:  console.log("Value = ", parameterValueText.text)

            }
        }
    }

    Row {
        spacing: 10
        Button {
            id: saveBtn
            text: "Save"
            onClicked: console.log("Save = ", parameterValueText.text)
        }

        Button {
            id: cancelBtn
            text: "Cancel"
            onClicked: val = 0 //Why the value is not changing in parameterValueText.text ?
        }
    }
}

InputPanel
{
    id:inputPanel
    y:parent.height
    width: window.width

    //Background for Virtual Keyboard
    Component{
        id:keyboardBackground
        Rectangle{
            color:"#f4f6f3"//ScreenConfiguration.backGroundCanvas
        }
    }
    states: State {
        name: "visible"
        when: inputPanel.active
        PropertyChanges {
            target: inputPanel
            y: parent.height - inputPanel.height
        }
        PropertyChanges {
            target: inputPanel
        }
    }
    transitions: Transition {
        from: ""
        to: "visible"
        reversible: true
        ParallelAnimation {
            NumberAnimation {
                properties: "y"
                duration: 200
                easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
            }
        }
    }
    Component.onCompleted: {
        keyboard.style.keyboardBackground = keyboardBackground;        // the keyboard background
    }
}
```

}

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
qputenv("QT_IM_MODULE", QByteArray("qtvirtualkeyboard"));

QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                 &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
    if (!obj && url == objUrl)
        QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
}, Qt::QueuedConnection);
engine.load(url);

return app.exec();
}
```

Add below change in .pro file for enabling virtual keyboard
QT += quick virtualkeyboard

The console log ouputs are below
qml: Value =  1, val =  0
qml: Save =  1, val =  0

Comment: I think what happens it that the TextInput actually overrides the `text` property (and thus removing the binding), can you extend the console.log's to log both values and add it to the question?

Comment: Yes, @Amfasis is right. The binding gets broken when you change the `text` property through user input. If it kept the binding, it would have to still match `val`, which was initialized to 0. That wouldn't be useful when you're trying to type in a new value for it.

Comment: @Amfasis - Thank you for your response and attached the console logs as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binding isn't maintained after the user changes the text using the `TextInput` (as commenters suggested).

To achieve similar results to what you were attempting you could set `val` in the `TextInput`'s `onAccepted` slot, and similarly update both `val` and `parameterValueText.text` in the `onClicked` slots for your buttons as appropriate. For example:

```
    TextInput {
        ...
        onAccepted: {
            val = text
        }
    }
//...
        Button {
            id: cancelBtn
            text: "Cancel"
            onClicked: {
                val = 0;
                parameterValueText.text = val;
            }
        }
```

This won't maintain the initial bindings because the values are assigned in imperative javascript, but should achieve resetting values as expected.

Answer (score 0):

As continuation on the answer of @dabbler, you can also recreate the binding in the `onAccepted` handler, but yeah it's still weird.

```
 parameterValueText.text = Qt.binding(function() { return val; })
```

As another solution, you could have the `val` property bind to the text of the input (which then starts with "0"):

```
readonly property int val: parseInt(parameterValueText.text)
```

But that only works if the `val` property is intended to be used as readonly (otherwise you will loose the binding again). In case you want the `val` property to be set from outside, you could do the following:

```
onValChanged: parameterValueText.text = val
```

Note that this is *assignment*, not binding!